# Bundle framework with application in XCode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I am an XCode novice.  I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://old.wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/How_to_link_Custom_Frameworks_from_your_Xcode_Projects). Clearly I am missing something because while I can see that the framework I want has been copied into the app bundle, I can't reference it.

When I start the application from a machine other than mine (or if I remove OpenCV from /Library/Frameworks/ ) I get the following error:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not
>   loaded:
>   /Users/david/Library/Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/Versions/A/OpenCV
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/g/Demo/Slates/ClipSplitter/build/Release/ClipSplitter.app/Contents/MacOS/ClipSplitter
>   Reason: image not found

There is no user "david" on my system if that makes any difference. Also this is a prebuilt OpenCV downloaded from the internet. ([Here’s a screenshot of the project](http://www.flickr.com/photos/xurble/4061498502/sizes/o/) as requested in comments.)

Comment: Where is it inside the app bundle?

Comment: Contents/Frameworks/OpenCV.framework

Comment: I'd say post a screenshot of your project window with the relevant target fully expanded.

Comment: After a long, illness induced delay, I have done so

Comment: I hope you're feeling better and your project is feeling better after applying my answer ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When the OpenCV.framework has been build it has been configured to use an install path of `/Users/david/Library/Frameworks/`.

Since you want to use the library as a private framework (installed in the application wrapper at `ClipSplitter.app/Contents/Frameworks/OpenCV.framework`) you have to change its install path. This can be done easily using the terminal as follows:

```
$ install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV <your_path>/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV
```

Of course you have to adjust the path of the last argument.

Now, when linking your application, your modified framework tells the linker that dyld has to search for the OpenCV.framework in the app wrapper of your application (in the ClipSplitter.app/Contents/Frameworks directory).

Now you have to copy the OpenCV.framework to your application wrapper. You can do this as part of your build process by adding a copy files build phase: Right-click on your target, select Add->New Build Phase->New Copy Files Build Phase. Select "Frameworks" from the "Destination" pop up and close the dialog.

Your target will now contain a new phase to which you can add the OpenCV.framework by dragging the icon from the Project Navigator on the left side of Xcode window. Note that Xcode won't allow you to add a folder to the Copy Files phase by using the '+' button so in order to copy the framework you'll have to drag&drop it.

Comment: This was almost completely right.  The command I actually had to run was:  $ install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV <your_path>/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV but this was more than enough to get me there.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Oops, right. That happens if you don't try what you're typing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you are installing more than one framework to the install path _that rely on each other_, though, this won't quite work. You need to also set the runpath search path in your xcode application to search in @loader_path/../Frameworks.
I found this explanation really helpful: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the build setting "Installation directory" to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`

See the chapter about Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html

Regards

Comment: You should at least mention that this setting has to by applied when building the framework, not the application that links the framework.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure this is good advice except I didn't build the OpenCV framework, I downloaded it prebuilt.

Comment: I missed the last sentence, Nikolai's answer is more appropriate in that case. I'm not sure why you would rather spend time fixing broken prebuilt open-source libraries rather than building them properly, though.

Comment: I thought it would be quicker.  And it was up until the point where I tried to run it on a different machine :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Xcode 5, you can facilitate this using the `Build Phases` panel of your application target.

The default appearance of this panel is [image]

By pressing the "+" button underneath **Copy Files**, you can add your framework as a file that will be copied into Frameworks in your app bundle.
[image]

Now, when you build, your Framework(s) will be copied into your bundle.

Comment: Images are dead. Re-upload?