# Sdl objective c++ and xcode include sdl framework in game

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl, objective-c++

I am writing my first game in SDL in xcode using objective C++.
The Program runs fine on my computer but I am trying to include the framework in the application so it can be played on other macs with out the need to install it.

I have set the framework to copy and then link to the binary in the application build phases.

Every time I run the application on another mac i get this error message:

> Process:         Maze [2911]
>   Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/Maze.app/Contents/MacOS/Maze
>   Identifier:      LKW.Maze
>   Version:         1 (1)
>   Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:  launchd [2811]
>   Date/Time:       2013-01-14 12:50:54.126 +1100
>   OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)
>   Report Version:  9
>   
>   Interval Since Last Report:          60055 sec
>   Crashes Since Last Report:           11
>   Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
>   Anonymous UUID:                      9FDDFA61-468F-4EE5-B922-EE167A9E7DF7
>   
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>   
>   Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
>   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
>   
>   Application Specific Information:
>   dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
>   
>   Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
>     Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Maze.app/Contents/MacOS/Maze
>     Reason: image not found
>   
>   Binary Images:
>          0x10ed3c000 -        0x10ed41fff +LKW.Maze (1 - 1) 5364749AEDEB> /Users/USER/Desktop/Maze.app/Contents/MacOS/Maze
>       0x7fff6e93c000 -     0x7fff6e970baf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <0CD1B35B-A28F-32DA-B72E-452EAD609613> /usr/lib/dyld
>       0x7fff8ba34000 -     0x7fff8bd4dfff  com.apple.Foundation (6.7.2 - 833.25) <22AAC369-B63C-3C55-8AC6-C3ECBA44DA7B> 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
>       0x7fff94742000 -     0x7fff94742fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.6 - ???) <7EC4D759-B2A6-3A99-AC75-809FED1500C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
>
> Model: MacBook7,1, BootROM MB71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.60f5
>   Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
>   Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837334648532D4346382020
>   Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142323837334648532D4346382020
>   AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
>   Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
>   Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
>   Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545025B9SA02, 250.06 GB
>   Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
>   USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0x24600000 / 2
>   USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06600000 / 3
>   USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0x06630000 / 5
>   USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0x06300000 / 2

Edit:
The SDL framework is in Contents > Frameworks in the app bundle.
I have tried Adam's work around.
I have included `@executable_path/contents/framworks` in the framework search paths.
I have tried both

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h" 
and 
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

Comment: It looks like a run-time crash. Run your program in a debugger, it will tell you _where_ the program crashed, let you see and walk the function call stack so you know how you ended up at the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you understand _why_ it crashed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621451/bundle-framework-with-application-in-xcode

Answer (score 1):

Check that the SDL framework was copied to the game's application bundle. Select the application from the Finder, right-click and choose Show Package Contents. The SDL framework should be in Contents > Frameworks in the app bundle if it was copied properly.

If the SDL framework wasn't copied to the app bundle, you can find instructions on how to copy the SDL framework to the app bundle in the following article:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

Make sure you read the comment from Adam in the article, as his comment contains a workaround if following the instructions in the article fails to copy the SDL framework to the app bundle.